# Python: result of get_connections in facebook.GraphAPI

Tags: python, facebook

In jupyter notebook, i tried the following code:

```
g = facebook.GraphAPI(User_Access_Token)
print(g.get_connections('me', 'friendlists'))
```

This gave me a bunch of id. 
help(g.get_connections) tells 
get_connections(self, id, connection_name, **args) method of facebook.GraphAPI instance
    Fetches the connections for given object.

But I really don't understand what does connections mean. I wanna know what are those ids represent and what are connected between me and friendlists.

Comment: Those are the ids of the friend lists. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @WizKid I'm learning how to query the Graph API with Python. I have some examples but those code have no explanations. So I don't quite understand. Yea, I guess those are the ids of the friend lists, but they seems have nothing to do with connection.